# How to get appModule properties in feature modules

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-mvvm, modularization

My project is having feature1Module and feature2Module. These 2 are included in app module
build gradle file.

```
implementation project(":feature1Module")
implementation project(":feature2Module")
```

I can access feature1Module and feature2Module's on app module but not able to access app module from feature1Module module.

Ex:-
**app** has DashboardFragment

**feature1Module** has Feature1Fragment

**feature2Module** has Feature2Fragment

I can navigate DashboardFragment to Feature1Fragment and Feature2Fragment but not able to navigate to DashboardFragment from Feature1Fragment beacause i cannot access DashboardFragment from Feature1Fragment.

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feature modules cant depend to app module. You need to create a common module ex `common`, then make app and feature module depend on it.

Suggestion

`common` has interface `Router`

```kotlin
interface Router {
  fun moveToDashboard()
}
```

`app` module

```kotlin
class AppRouter : Router {
  override fun moveToDashboard() {
    // your logic here
  }
}
```

`feature` module, call to `common`

```kotlin
private val router: Router = // init logic, maybe call setter from app

router.moveToDashboard()
```

Comment: Thank you and Can you please tell how to do this using dagger hilt DI @dinhlam

Comment: Because We will be not having AppRouter reference in common to pass in DI's module class

Comment: with hilt, you can `provide` an instance of AppRouter and inject it in needed module